# How to get number from url which is stored in a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, url

I have string as page url like this: - artist.php?id=6 or album.php?id=23
I want to get that value of id how to get that in javascript.

Comment: I want values in javaScript.

Comment: You want id from window url or just from a string ?

Comment: just from a string if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should try this**

In `JavaScript` you can get values from `URL` of any param using a function that in below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
                sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                sParameterName,
                i;
        for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
            }
        }
    };

    var id = getUrlParameter('id');
});
```

I know it was long code but using this method you can get values of any param.

> var id = getUrlParameter('id');
>
> var anyparam = getUrlParameter('param_name');

Comment: @ShashankDubey What is your full url?

Comment: sorry i made mistake solution in JavaScript not in Php

Comment: full url is  /BasicPhp/Spotify/artist.php?id=28

Comment: @ShashankDubey I've modified answer.Please check it

Comment: What if i need number just from a string

Comment: You'll get any values from `URL` of query string